# Android 5.0 - Animate the AppCompat v7 21 home icon from burger to back arrow programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, drawertoggle

I'm currently updating a `Fragment` oriented app (I have one `Activity` with a `FrameLayout` container as host for all my `Fragment`s) to Material Design. And I would like to animate the burger icon to the back arrow when replacing a `Fragment`.

Basically, if this wasn't clear enough, [**here**](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_1/quantumexternal/0B0NGgBg38lWWNkJYYXZvcGFXZDg/animation-responsiveinteraction-userinput-030201_Radial_Reaction_xhdpi_001.webm) is what I want to achieve. I don't want to use [**this library (MaterialMenu)**](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu), I'd like to use the official `AppCompat` lib to the extend of possible.

I achieved this effect thanks to [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480439/3108590), but I can't figure out how to make to `ActionBarDrawerToggle` as a back button when a `Fragment` is replaced.

So my questions is : should the back arrow icon still be the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`once the `Fragement` has been replaced? In which case how do I override it so it acts like `onBackPressed()` instead of openning the drawer ? I already tried this but it doesn't work :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's a little cleaner to track inside the drawer toggle if you've manually opened it or not. This is what I ended up doing:

```
public class ManualActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {
    private static final float MENU_POSITION = 0f;
    private static final float ARROW_POSITION = 1.0f;

    private final int animationLength;
    private final DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private final Activity activity;
    private State currentState;

    private enum State { UP_ARROW, MENU }

    public ManualActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescriptionResource, int closeDrawerContentDescriptionResource) {
        super(activity, drawerLayout, openDrawerContentDescriptionResource, closeDrawerContentDescriptionResource);
        animationLength = activity.getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        this.activity = activity;
        currentState = State.MENU;
    }

    public void animateToBackArrow() {
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(MENU_POSITION, ARROW_POSITION);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            onDrawerSlide(drawerLayout, slideOffset);
            }
        });

        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(animationLength);
        anim.start();

        currentState = State.UP_ARROW;
    }

    public void animateToMenu() {
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ARROW_POSITION, MENU_POSITION);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                onDrawerSlide(drawerLayout, slideOffset);
            }
        });

        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(animationLength);
        anim.start();

        currentState = State.MENU;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case (android.R.id.home):
                if (currentState == State.UP_ARROW) {
                    activity.onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
Before initializing everything

Answer (score 1):

Menu drawable of this library has a method that can animate states:

If you want to switch from `Burger` to `Arrow` you do this call:

```
mMaterialMenu.animateState(IconState.ARROW);
```

Comment: Indeed, and as I said, I already used it but imo it's not as good looking than the stock icon :).

Comment: Then, why dont you switch to v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: Well, I did...? What I want is not the toggle animation while openning/closing the drawer; it's the same animation but when switching fragments. And I'd like the toggle to act like the home/back arrow once a Fragment is added

Comment: Use this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: How can we keep default Menu Drawable to `X` state in xml. I am using in activity `mMaterialMenu.animateState(IconState.X);` to switch from default `Burger` Menu to `X` one. But it changes with animation. I didn't find any attribute to change state in xml. Please help.

Comment: I found what it is, instead of using `mMaterialMenu.animateState(IconState.X);` I should use `mMaterialMenu.setState(IconState.X);` from which I was able to change state from default `BURGER` to `X` without animation,though I didn't find any attribute to set in `xml`.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I figured out a way. I'm pretty sure it's NOT a good solution as I'm using the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` for a different purpose than what it was created for.

But it works, so here's what I did. I simply created a custom `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in which I override the `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` method :

```
class MyDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle
{
    // ... Default constructors matching super go here

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // If the back stack isn't empty, ie if I'm not in a Fragment 
        // accessible from the NavigationDrawer, I simulate the onBackPressed behaviour
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0)
        {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to propose.